# Jquery form defend at atacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The goal is to keep track of incorrectly entered data into the form, or rather after 5 unsuccessful attempts to ban anything given over 15 minutes. Brute force by a dreadful

Comment: You'll want to use server-side code for this, not client-side code.  If somebody is trying to brute-force attack your form then they're probably not going to use your own client-side code to accomplish it.

Comment: Use server-side not client-side. Put datetime values on session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, detecting incorrect input, you can use a *validation* library, of which the following is the most popular:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

For the second bit (banning people for a set time) you are going to need to do something on the server-side. Log the I.P. address in a database table called "banned_ips", along with the current time plus 15 minutes. Certainly not something you can do with jQuery...